# Some Updates missing in my Eclipse or errors in source code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

My developer (freelancer) just finished working on app and sent me the source code folder. When I loaded it in my Eclipse (as I wanted to export signed apk for google play store) it lists around 1000 errors. So I wanted to ask your experienced opinion if there is most probably something wrong with my Exclipse (missing some package update or something) or there is actually something wrong with code sent or elements/ files missing?

All errors are something like:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No recourse found that matched the given name "Theme.App"...
>   ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type
>   BitmapDescriptionFactory cannot be resolved
>   etc. so about 1020 like those in total.

Comment: Among possibly other things, it sounds like you need to update the attached Android library projects, like `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: Oh. Ok. will try to do it as well. through where should I do it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Thanks. Will try that. Perhaps it will help to remove at least few errors.